# Automatically update sheet 2 & sheet 3 from sheet 1 as per data

Tags: vba, excel

I want to automatically update sheet 2 & sheet 3 from sheet 1 as per data. It will be helpful if it gets resolved.

I am new to visual basic coding so unaware of its script but aware of c++. Whatever the solution may be it will be helpful.

#### Screen shot of the three sheets - I was unable to upload the Excel files

[image: screenshot]

I have tried the following code:

```
Sub FindMatches()
    Dim oldrow As Integer
    Dim newrow As Integer
     For oldrow = 4 To 14
        For newrow = 3 To 20
            If Cells(oldrow, 12) = Cells(1, newrow) And Cells(oldrow, 13) = Cells(newrow, 1) Then  'date and brand
                    If Cells(1, 14) = Cells(newrow, 2) Then
                          Cells(newrow, 3).Value = Cells(oldrow, 14).Value ' m1
                    End If
                    If Cells(1, 15) = Cells(newrow + 1, 2) Then
                          Cells(newrow + 1, 3).Value = Cells(oldrow, 15).Value ' m2
                    End If
                    If Cells(1, 16) = Cells(newrow + 2, 2) Then
                                    Cells(newrow + 2, 3).Value = Cells(oldrow, 16).Value ' m3
                    End If
                    If Cells(1, 17) = Cells(newrow + 3, 2) Then
                                        Cells(newrow + 3, 3).Value = Cells(oldrow, 17).Value ' issue
                    End If
                    If Cells(1, 18) = Cells(newrow + 4, 2) Then
                                            Cells(newrow + 4, 3).Value = Cells(oldrow, 18).Value ' repack
                    End If
                    If Cells(1, 19) = Cells(newrow + 5, 2) Then
                                                Cells(newrow + 5, 3).Value = Cells(oldrow, 19).Value ' extra
                    End If
                    If Cells(1, 20) = Cells(newrow + 6, 2) Then
                    Cells(newrow + 6, 3).Value = Cells(oldrow, 20).Value ' wastage
                    End If
         End If

        Next newrow
        Next oldrow
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you even don't need VBA to update the data. You can simply enter a formula `=C2` into a cell to reference (and retrieve the data from) a cell.

You also can reference cells from other sheets like this `=Sheet1!C2`.

And you can use Functions such as [IF](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if.php) to do more complex cases and logic.

Answer (score 0):

You just cant use `Cells` without sheet referencing. Because excel dont know which sheet you wana to use and assuming active sheet. So you need to you `ActiveSheet.cells()` and switching active sheet (but its not highly recommended). Instead use sheet declaration like this

```
Dim myLovelySheet as worksheet
Set mylovelySheet = Sheets("yourCuteSheetname")
```

and then you can work with sheet like with object (you will be familiar to it from C++)

```
myLovelySheet.cells()
```

or you can perform multiple operations on sheet with construction like this

```
with myLovelySheet
.cells()
.cells()
'etc

end with
```

Basicaly your approach is almost correct, but try study more code. I can recommend [this](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/MainPage.aspx) which have multiple examples with good practise

Comment: thaks for your appriciation,